# Consuming broadbandmap.gov json service errors

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to consume the json services from broadbandmap.gov so that I can display broadband providers and their speeds in an area. Here is a sample url:

http://www.broadbandmap.gov/internet-service-providers/70508/lat=30.1471824/long=-92.033638/%3Ejson

I'm using jquery to consume the service, however it's giving me an invalid label error in firebug:

```
var url = "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/internet-service-providers/70508/lat=30.1471824/long=-92.033638/%3Ejson";
        //var url = "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/broadband/fall2010/wireline?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + long + "&format=json";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                console.debug("in success");
                console.debug(result);
                //success, execute callback function.
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.debug("in error");
                console.debug(result);
            }
        });
```

The strange thing is that under the Invalid Label error in Firebug it actually has the correct response:

{"status":"OK","responseTime":7,"messa...//www.cscic.state.ny.us/broadband/"}}}

I have tried setting the dataType to json, jsonp, and other types as well to no avail. I have also tried GET instead of POST but that didn't work either. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is occurring because the service is returning JSON and not JSONP. Your browser is not going to let you process straight JSON from a cross-domain source.

In order to make the service return JSONP you have to use a specially formatted URL.  If you go to the search results page without the "/>json" modifier ([link](http://www.broadbandmap.gov/internet-service-providers/70508/lat=30.1471824/long=-92.033638/)) you'll see a link on the page that reads "API Call".  If you hover over this link it will give you the correct URL to use for the wireless/wired API call.  Use one of those URL's in your ajax call with a JSONP return type & callback and you should be all set.

I created an updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qsY7h/1/.

Comment: Wow, you were right on. I had the api call url (commented out in the question's code) and tried that with the jsonp data type, however I was missing the callback param. I had seen in firebug that jquery creates a callback param so didn't think I had to manually create it, but that worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross-domain request so you should use JSONP datatype - the API supports this return type.  The URL you provided in your example didn't return anything for me so I checked out [Broadbandmap's Developer Docs](http://www.broadbandmap.gov/developer/api) and found an alternate call.  Please find an example at http://jsfiddle.net/szCAF/.

The most important point to note is "callback=?" in the URL. jQuery uses this to tell the API what function name to wrap around the output (this is all done transparently by jQuery).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, I tried setting setting the dataType to "jsonp", which appends a callback parameter to the url, however it didn't work. This url didn't work for you - http://www.broadbandmap.gov/internet-service-providers/70508/lat=30.1471824/long=-92.033638/%3Ejson ??

Comment: It wasn't working yesterday but it's working now. I posted a new answer based on the info I found on that page.